# DomPDF Image not found or type unknown

Tags: php, silverstripe, dompdf

Technologies used:

```
PHP: v7.4
SilverStripe: v4.7
DomPDF: 1.0
```

[image: Composer]

Before posting this, I made sure that I was able to follow the other tips and articles that are related to this DomPDF not showing the included image, but the image still ins't working

[image: Image not found]

Code-wise, I have already enabled the `setIsRemoteEnabled` option for the DomPDF, as per some of the devs mentioned in the github page

[image: Classes]

[image: DomPDF Options]

Here's the endpoint 1/2 
[image: Endpoint]

Endpoint 2/2 
[image: Endpoint 2]

Here's the Invoice generator 
[image: FE]

Looking at the generated invoice, I was able to display the path of the image, and when I click to it, it's being displayed properly 
[image]

[image: Image 2]

It's just that the image isn't working for DomPDF, did I miss anything or is there a wrong code in my codebase? Would be very grateful for your help, been stuck for 4 days now

Comment: Without really understanding *everything*, I see "$logo" and "$Logo" in your code (upper-/lowercase L). Could that maybe be the reason?

Comment: Hello sir Johannes! In a SilverStripe concept I have the $response_data variable, I passed it to the front end as "Logo", so the template of SilverStripe recognized it as $Logo in the FE :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to finally get a technique!

[image]

Instead of adding the file path, just convert your images into Base64, worked like a charm!

[image]

Here's the code snippet for an easy copy paste

```
// Get Base64 of the Logo
$path = Director::baseFolder() .'/public'.$config->WebsiteLogo()->getURL();
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$logo = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: in my case i have to pass public path Like : "public_path('media/images/qrcode/qrcode_'.$property->reference.'.png');"